# How to get all variables when an error happens in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a custom error handler in my PHP application, I would like to get the variables defined when the error happened.

To achieve that I use this code:

```
    function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
        ..some stuff..
        ob_start();
        var_dump(get_defined_vars());
        $environment = ob_get_clean();
        ..some other stuff..
    }
```

What happens is that it returns only the variables defined in the error_handler. What I would like is this code to return all the variables and not only the ones defined in the error_handler. Is there a scope problem that I don't understand here or does the issue comes from elsewhere?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Comment: Got that from a simple google `php show all variables`

Comment: PHP only has [local variable scopes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) throughout. With the shared ("global") scope being the only thing you could possibly see. Parent function scopes are inaccessible. Only option would be [xdebug`s stack_trace](https://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace). Which is not gonna help with your custom error handler though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Have you even looked at my example?

Comment: @mario I could look into dumping xdebug's stack trace into a file when it happens to be triggered. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after considering other's answers and looking a bit further on the internet, I have come with an alternative solution that helps me to get more information when debugging an error.

The debug_print_backtrace function from PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Also as mentioned by mario, I could add a hook on xdebug's to eventually dump it to a file. Not sure if this is possible though.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by creating a file where I store every variable in right before the error in combination with custom error handling.

getvars.php: (note this is not a function, just some code you include to your page)

```
<?php
    $variables = get_defined_vars();
    $ignore = array('GLOBALS', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET', '_SERVER', '_ENV', 'ignore');
    // diff the ignore list as keys after merging any missing ones with the defined list
    $vars = array_diff_key($variables + array_flip($ignore), array_flip($ignore));
    $values="";
    foreach ($vars as $var => $value){
        if(!is_array($value) && !is_object($value)){
            $values.=$var."=".strval($value).";";
        }
    }
    //create the file
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $filename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/".$ip.".txt";
    $tmpFile = fopen($filename,"wb");
    fwrite($tmpFile,$values);
    fclose($tmpFile);
?>
```

error_log.php: (the custom error handler)

```
<?php
    set_error_handler("errorHandler");
    register_shutdown_function("shutdownHandler");
    function errorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context){
        $error = $error_message." | ".$error_file." | line:".$error_line;
        switch ($error_level) {
            case E_ERROR:
            case E_CORE_ERROR:
            case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
            case E_PARSE:
                mylog($error, "(fatal)");
                break;
            case E_USER_ERROR:
            case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
                mylog($error, "(error)");
                break;
            case E_WARNING:
            case E_CORE_WARNING:
            case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
            case E_USER_WARNING:
                mylog($error, "(warn)");
                break;
            case E_NOTICE:
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
                mylog($error, "(info)");
                break;
            case E_STRICT:
                mylog($error, "(debug)");
                break;
            default:
                mylog($error, "(warn default)");
        }
    }
    function shutdownHandler(){ //will be called when php script ends.
        $lasterror = error_get_last();
        if($lasterror!=null){
            switch ($lasterror['type']){
                case E_ERROR:
                case E_CORE_ERROR:
                case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
                case E_USER_ERROR:
                case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
                case E_WARNING:
                case E_CORE_WARNING:
                case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
                case E_USER_WARNING:
                case E_NOTICE:
                case E_USER_NOTICE:
                case E_STRICT:
                case E_PARSE:
                    $error = $lasterror['message']." | ".$lasterror['file']." | line:".$lasterror['line'];
                    mylog($error, "fatal");
            }
        }
    }
    function mylog($error, $errlvl){
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        error_log($error." ".$errlvl."\n"."https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] ",0);
        $filename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/".$ip.".txt";
        if (file_exists($filename)){ //read the file and add it to the log
            $file=fopen($filename, "r");
            $variables=fread($file, filesize($filename));
            error_log("Variables: ".$variables,0);
        }
    }
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
    $a=1;
    $b=0;
    include("./getvars.php");
    require_once("./error_log.php");
    echo $a/$b; //an error :-)
?>
```

I hope this is still useful for someone :-)

Comment: This is useful when you know an error can happen here, and it's actually what I have done. But when you don't know if an error could happen or not, it's not very usable in the way that I cannot dump all variables before every single operation I have to perform. 
Thanks for sharing your code, it might help people in some cases :)

Comment: I know. It can be useful if you dump the variables at the start of the page (just above where you start your "real" code), so you know the value of some variables you get from _get and _post requests. If there's an error you have at least some basic information and you can add the vardump above the right line, because the error will occur again at some point :-)